# How to chain a condition for multiple arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

I created a condition for an array which if the last value in a row is less than the first value in the next row, then increases the next row by +10.
I tried to do this for multiple arrays in a row, which it reads from the input in a row. The problem is that with each matrix, it starts working from the beginning. Is it possible to chain it somehow so that the condition on consecutive matrices follows each other?

Input

```
[[11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
 [21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29]] 

[[31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 42]
 [41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 52]
 [51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 62]] 

[[61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71]
 [71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81]
 [81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91]]
```

this is the part of the code where I work with it

```
sedem[1:][sedem[:-1,-1] >= sedem[1:, 0]] += 10
```

can it be concatenated so that with each nut the condition does not start from the beginning but continues?

my output:

```
[[11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
 [21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29]] 

[[31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 42]
 [51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 62]
 [61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 72] 

[[ 61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71]
 [ 81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91]
 [ 91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101]]
```

I need

required output:

```
[[11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
 [21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29]] 

[[31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 42]
 [51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 62]
 [61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 72]] 

[[ 71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81]
 [ 91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99  100  101]
 [ 111  112  113  114  115  116  117  118  119 120 121]]
```

I read the values from demofile.txt in the whole code and convert them into arrays and then manipulate them

I also attach the entire code with comments

full code:

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
     

#read data
f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
#input preprocessing
p=1
for i in list(lines):
    if i[0] != '<' and i[0] != '>' and i[0] != '=':
        d = str(' '.join(i.split()))
        print(d)
            
    else:
        w = i.replace("=",'')
        w = w.replace(">",'')
        w = w.replace("<",'')
        w = ', '.join(w.split())
        c=np.array([w])            
        c1 = [int(i) for i in c[0].replace(" ", "").split(",")]
         #insert input to array
        c1=np.array(c1)
        # save first value in array
        frst=c1[0]
         #remove first value in array
        c1=np.delete(c1, 0)       
        n=len(c1)
        #multiply array
        c1=np.array([c1]*frst)
        #print(c1)       
        
        #transpose array
        c1=np.transpose(c1)
        #adding a value to each row
        left = np.array([[(p + j) * 10  for j in range(frst)]] * n) +c1 
                 
        left=left*-1
        sedem=np.transpose(left)*-1
    
        
        #condition
        sedem[1:][sedem[:-1,-1] >= sedem[1:, 0]] += 10
        print(sedem,'\n')
              
        p +=frst
```

demofile.txt

```
<=2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  
<=3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 12 
<=3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to merge the lists so that all of the rows are together

```
l1 = [[11,12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
 [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]] 

l2 = [[31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 42],
 [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 52],
 [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 62]] 

l3 = [[61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71],
 [71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81],
 [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91]] 

biglist = l1
biglist.extend(l2)
biglist.extend(l3)

for index, item in enumerate(biglist):
    try:
        # if last element of l is greater than first element of next row
        if item[len(item) - 1] > biglist[index + 1][0]:
            print('adding 10 to row {}'.format(i))
            biglist[index + 1] = [m + 10 for m in biglist[index + 1]]
        
    except IndexError:
        pass
biglist
```

This outputs the rows in one big list

```
adding 10 to row 7
adding 10 to row 7
adding 10 to row 7
adding 10 to row 7
adding 10 to row 7
[[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
 [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
 [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 42],
 [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 62],
 [61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 72],
 [71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81],
 [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91],
 [91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101]]
```

If you needed to keep the separation you could store the lengths of the original lists (l1, l2 and l3) and then split this list based on those lengths.

Comment: it won't work like this, because in my code the fields go through iteratively and we can't connect them, can't the next one be otherwise?